# How to add active class dynamically in jquery for .net <asp:Menu></asp:Menu>

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

my code is here
I have use bootstrap use this code

```
            IncludeStyleBlock="false" StaticMenuStyle-CssClass="nav navbar-nav" StaticMenuItemStyle-CssClass="active">
        </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: the question is not clear to me, please explain what you need as clearer as you can

Comment: sir i have use .net default menu but my active class not working.